# What is the maximum byte size or limit of characters in label in lightning-cli invoice? Are UTF-8 characters accepted?

Tags: core-lightning, invoices

I'm writing a script [in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)) that is mean to make the usage of my c-lightning wallet more convenient. And so I have to
specify a limit of characters (`l` is a variable that stands for label):

```
puts("The label(a unique string or number)?");
        char l[15];
        fgets(l, 15, stdin);
        l[strcspn(l, "\n")] = 0;
```

I arbitrarily decided on 15 not knowing whether `lightning-cli invoice` would accept such long string. Although `help invoice` gives some info about the label:

> The  label  must be a unique string or number (which is treated as a string, so "01" is different
> from "1"); it is never revealed to other nodes on the lightning network, but it can  be  used  to
> query the status of this invoice.

it does not specify it's length nor its character set? Are [UTF-8 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) accepted within the label or should I use only [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set? What is the maximum size / number of characters of the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code you can find the data base schema of the SQLite3 database that is being used to store invoices at: https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/426ff0abfff8b080b22095b9f0b670c7192f54ea/wallet/db.c#L185

This indicates that the label field is of type TEXT. [According to the SQLite3 Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) this means:

> TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

Of course you need to check the if lightningd can also handle such long strings. the labels are stored in `invoice_details` which which is defined at:

https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/335ef3fb69f923f6f30213f68881d10ee6d977ed/wallet/wallet.h#L777

from there you can see that it is of type `* json_escape` which comes from rusty's ccan libraries and is defined at:

https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/ade10e7fc4dacbb9d635b05152c7dc38c0896ce7/ccan/ccan/json_escape/json_escape.h

There it says:

```
/* Type differentiation for a correctly-escaped JSON string */
struct json_escape {
    /* NUL terminated string. */
    char s[1];
};

/**
 * json_escape - escape a valid UTF-8 string.
 * @ctx: tal context to allocate from.
 * @str: the string to escape.
 *
 * Allocates and returns a valid JSON string (without surrounding quotes).
 */
struct json_escape *json_escape(const tal_t *ctx, const char *str TAKES);
```

To my understanding this indicates indeed that as long as you have memory and disc you should be able to store UTF-8 strings of arbitrary length.

Comment: Thank for this great answer. It is stated in `json_escape.h`: `struct json_escape { char s[1]; };` . I'm a newbie to C, but doesn't it mean that the maximum size of the label is just one char? It wouldn't make sense but I think that the general syntax for declaring a string in C is: `char variable_name [array_size];`

Comment: No as mentioned in my answer `invoice_details` includes a pointer to that struct so effectively it is an array of those wrapped 1 element char arrays. I myself are a bit confused why it can be used to store utf8 but I guess they take the char as a byte and have the encoding in there. The reason for doing a one element array from the stack instead of a variable however is mysterious to me.